# Convergence Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Whats the difference between the Theorem of Carleson and the convergence of the Fourier Series in the quadratic mean?

Answer (score 1):

The Fourier series of any $L^{2}$ function converges in $L^{2}$ (i.e. in quadratic mean) and this is a very easy result to prove once you kow the basic facts about orthonormal functions. The very deep result of Carelson says that the Fourier series of any $L^{2}$ function converges at almost all points.